# Get newest 5 WordPress posts per category

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, posts

I want to fetch the newest 5 published WordPress Posts per category in an external application. Those application is build in ASP.NET so I want to fetch the data directly from the MySQL-Database using EF. Building the WordPress relations in EF seems horrible so I want to build a custom model which holds the category details and information about the newest posts.

So I wrote an SQL query which works, BUT because of the aggregative group by it gave me only ONE row (post) per category:

```
Select terms.term_id As Id, terms.name As Name, terms.slug As SeoName, Group_Concat(relations.object_id) As PostId, taxonomy.count As Count, taxonomy.parent As ParentId,
(
    Select post_title
    From wp_posts 
    Where ID In(Group_Concat(relations.object_id))
    Order By post_date Desc
) As PostTitle
From wp_terms terms, wp_term_taxonomy taxonomy, wp_term_relationships relations
Where terms.term_id = taxonomy.term_id
And relations.term_taxonomy_id = taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
And taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
Group By terms.term_id
```

My idea was to add `Having Count(terms.term_id) = 5` so that I get 5 rows per category. But it's not working, I got an empty result. Without the `Having` I get one line per category with the newest post.

How can I tell MySQL to return 5 rows per category WITHOUT removing the grouping?

Lets say I have tree categories:

- CatA
- CatB
- CatC

Then I want to get the following result from the database (in short):

```
CategoryId | CategoryName | NewestPostTitle

1          | CatA     | Newest post in CatA
1          | CatA     | Second newest post in CatA
...
2          | CatB     | Newest post in CatB
2          | CatB     | Second newest post in CatB
...
3          | CatC     | Newest post in CatC
3          | CatC     | Second newest post in CatC
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Why aren't you looping through the categories, and querying the posts by each iteration with simple WP_Query (or get_posts())?

Answer (score 0):

Why arent you using built in wordpress functions? Please try the below code, I've tested it and it works fine for my tests:

```
$categories = get_categories();

/* echo '<pre>';
print_r($categories);
echo '</pre>'; */

foreach($categories as $category){
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'cat' => $category->term_id,
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    echo $category->name . '<hr />';

    while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();
        echo the_title() . '<br />';
    endwhile;
}
```

Edit: I didnt realize you wanted to use this in an external app. I would use the code I provided and create a page template that would return the results in an array or in json format.

You can also echo the query wordpress uses to grab the data and build off of that. You can do so by echoing $query->request;

e.g.

Grab a list of wordpress categories via:

```
SELECT t.term_id AS id
FROM   wp_terms t
       LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt
              ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE  tt.taxonomy = 'category'
ORDER  BY name
```

Loop through the results and grab the latest 5 entries from the term_id:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (5) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.ID DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

Replace `wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (6)` with the respective ID from the loop.